# What is the proper way of running Gatling from a stand-alone application

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to start a Gatling simulation from a main application. The use case is as follows:

- The application reads a specification, and generate test cases based on this specification.
- The test cases are converted into Gatling scenarios.
- The scenarios are run in a Gatling simulation.

So far I managed to do this via the sbt plugin. However this is inconvenient if we want to reuse the tool I'm developing in other contexts (imagine non-scala projects for instance).

Since I'm generating Gatling scenarios dynamically which means that I cannot simply pass a Scala class to the Gatling binary.

I was able to run the simulation as follows:

```
Gatling.fromArgs(args, Some(classOf[Simulation]), _ => new ValidationTest)
```

Where `ValidationTest` is the class that generates the scenarios dynamically. However, I'm not sure that is the proper way of using Gatling in a standalone application.